# Get cell value from table - flutter

Tags: flutter, csv, dart, datatable

I have created a table from an imported CSV file, I have set this table to be hidden as I don't want the user to actually see the table.

I have also created a custom widget to be reused several times throughout my app, it's just a container that displays some text. Here is the code for the table:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class RouteNameTable extends StatefulWidget {
  const RouteNameTable({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RouteNameTableState createState() => _RouteNameTableState();
}

class _RouteNameTableState extends State<RouteNameTable> {
  List<List<dynamic>> data = [];

  void loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/routes.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = const CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
    data = csvTable;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadAsset();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Visibility(
        visible: false,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Table(
            border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0),
            children: data.map((item) {
              return TableRow(
                  children: item.map((row) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: Text(
                      row.toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList());
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

The custom widget I created is just a container that displays a number, name and has a colour. When inserting the widget I use the following code

```
const RouteTemplate(
              routeNumber: '33',
              routeName: 'Corstorphine - Caversham - City - Wakari',
              routeColor: Color(0xFFF067A6),
            ),
```

This works correctly. However, what I want to do is replace the text (such as '33') that I have typed with data from the table I created. It will still say 33 but instead of me typing it, it retrieves the first column in the second row as `routeNumber`, the second column in the second row as `routeName` and so on. I would like this as the CSV file may change, and instead of having to add/remove/change the route number, once the new CSV file is added it will do it automatically.

Thanks